# PHP: PDO Fetch Class

Tags: php, pdo

I wanted to know if there was a way to work with a result from a fetch class command without using the foreach loop.  I'm trying to create a login function that puts the user info into a class.

Is there a way to get get data from a class that holds just one result without  loop?

```
$result = $dbquery->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "userclass");
echo $result->username;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just just use [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

```
$dbquery->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "userclass");
$result = $dbquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```